# Pandas or any other way to run this fastest?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, large-data, python-polars

dfA:

| Var1 | Var2 | Var3 | Var4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12.5 | 13.2 | 4.56 | 7.98 |
| 14.1 | 11.9 | 5.76 | 8.91 |
| 12.9 | 10.0 | 7.0 | 9.2 |

dataframe A above contains 10 Million rows

listB:
[ df1, df2, df3, df4]

listB above contains 4 dataframes with about 8000 rows each.

I have to take each df from listB, take each row of dfA and apply the foo(), and add them all together and store. So at first pass, the process should take df1, apply the 1st value of Var1 on df1, take df2, apply the first value of Var 2 and so on and add all of them together and store. Essentially I want to get 10M values out of all these.

I even tried np.Vectorize but to no use.

I tried non-pythonic way with loops ( I know it is not optimal) but it just hangs the machine.

```
def foo(df):
     newlist.append(dosomething(var))

newlist=[]
for j in range(len(dfA)-1):
    for i in range(len(listB)-1):
        newlist.append(np.vectorize(foo)(dfA.iloc[j,i])
    newlist.sum()
```

I have an intuition that a list comprehension is a better bet here. Any thoughts on what is the most optimal/quickest way to attain this please?

Many thanks,

R

*I am editing this post for better readability and more details and example output*:

```
def foo(df,val):
    y=((df['v1']/df['v2'])*val)
    return(y)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

So as you can see I have to apply the function 10M * 4 times; After passing the 4 variables over the 4 dataframes, i need to add the result. So, one sum per row .Thank you.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/akVTc.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsubf.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVcDM.jpg

Comment: could you post a reproducible example with expected output please?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Thanks for looking. I have re-edited and posted it.

Comment: Hi Raghu, ignoring_gravity meant [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: To elaborate further.  Screen captures of your data are not helpful to people that might want to help you.  Look at some other polars questions and see how most askers put their sample data in a copy-pasteable `df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})` format.

Comment: Thanks @dankal444 & Dean Macgregor; I will try to amend it to suit the format.